# google appstore sales report download automation

Tags: php, google-api, google-api-php-client

I'm doing a request with the google api library and trying to download some report to automate the download and import to our system. However I'm running into issues.
The error code I'm getting :

> Google\Cloud\Core\Exception\ServiceException: { "error": { "errors": [ { "domain": "global", "reason": "forbidden", "message": "service-worker@service-worker.iam.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.objects.list access to pubsite_prod_rev_." } ], "code": 403, "message": "service-worker@service-worker.iam.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.objects.list access to pubsite_prod_rev_." } } in D:\USER\Web\Directory\tools\vendor\google\cloud\Core\src\RequestWrapper.php on line 263

I've tried adding permisions to the pubsite_prod_dev directory I'm trying to access, however I'm getting another error, even though I'm the admin :

> You don't have permission to view this bucket's metadata. Contact the bucket owner to grant you the "storage.buckets.get" and "storage.buckets.getIamPolicy" permissions.

I know about the gsutil tool, and I used it successfully, the issue is that I can't use it in our tooling server because the hosting provider denied us this software (Using managed hosting). So I'm stuck with trying to make the API libraries work. 
Any good solutions to this? I've already tried all kinds of libraries and code found in github, however nothing seems to be working, or is outdated and the libraries are not deprecated. ..
My code:

```
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Google\Cloud\Storage\StorageClient;

$client  = new StorageClient([
    'scopes' => [StorageClient::READ_ONLY_SCOPE],
    'keyFile' => json_decode(file_get_contents('./client_secret.json'), true)
]);

$bucket = $client->bucket('pubsite_prod_rev_<code>');

foreach ($bucket->objects(['prefix' => 'sales/']) as $object) {
    print_r($object->name());
}

$file = $bucket->object('salesreport_201809.zip');
$file->downloadToFile();
```

Comment: Contact the owner of the bucket and have them give you permission to access it.

Comment: I'm logged in to the main account which should be the owner of the bucket

Comment: It says that the user you have authenticated doesn't have access.   Find the user who does and login with that or grant this user access.   You are also only requesting readonly access if your going to write something thats not oging to work.

Comment: i'm never will try to write, only download the files, Added the user to the list in the bucket, however the error is the same...

Comment: Did you reauthecate your application to get a new access token?  If so i would wait 10 minutes it can take a while for the permissions to work there way out

Comment: yes, the issue still persists

Answer (score 0):

This answer comes maybe to late. I had the same issue and remembered a sentence somwhere in the google docs stating that users who have permissions to the reports inside the Google Play Console also have access to the bucket where these reports are stored.

So the trick is to add the service account email (which you created to gain access to the cloud api with the StorageClient) to the Users inside Google Play Console.